# How to bind a repeater with 2 stored procedures both varying by 1 column. First output is ABCD , second output is EBCD

Tags: stored-procedures

how can you bind a repeater with 2 stored procedures, both stored procedures vary by 1 column , the output of 1 is ABCD then of the second is EBCD.

**UPDATE**

```
<asp:Repeater ....>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        [table rows and columns structure]
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        [table rows and columns structure]
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

1. data type of both a and E is string.
2. I am binding it to db through databind().
3. my markup looks like:

thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the data-type of columns A and E?
2. How are you binding? DataSourceId? DataSource/DataBind()?
3. What markup do you have in your repeater?

At the presentation layer (aspx page) it's all just strings so potentially you can just bind the repeater to either result as they both have 4 columns.

It's difficult to offer much more help as you haven't shown what you have already, and the best solution very much depends on the specifics of your project.

**EDIT**

Ok, then just bind it, have you not tried that yet? you will find when asking technical questions if you haven't tried something first, we are less likely to bother giving up our free time to help.

A better question would have been: "I have tried binding my repeater to 2 different stored procedures that differ by only one column, but I am getting an error (describe the exact error message). Here is my code ... can anyone help?"

**Possible solution**

aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterId" runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="RepeaterId_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        [table rows and columns structure]
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Literal ID="literalId" runat="server"></td>
            <td><% # eval("column2")%></td>
            <td><% # eval("column3")%></td>
            <td><% # eval("column4")%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void RepeaterId_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Literal lit = e.FindControl("literalId") as Literal;
        if(null != lit)
        {
            if(usingStoredProcedure1)
            {
                lit.Text = Databinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "A");
            }
            else
            {
                lit.Text = Databinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "E");
            }
        }
    }
}

private void BindRepeater()
{
    if(someCondition == true)
    {
        repeaterId.DataSource = getStoredProcedure1();
    }
    else 
    {
        repeaterId.DataSource = getStoredProcedure2();
    }

    repeaterId.DataBind();
}
```